# NSLayoutConstraint alternative in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nslayoutconstraint

**Exact task:**

Add [SKLabelNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sklabelnode?language=objc) to the left bottom conner of the screen.

The only way I found is to override size.

```
override var size: CGSize {

    didSet {
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY)
    }

}
```

And set alignment while configuring. in [sceneDidLoad](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1645216-scenedidload) for example.

```
    self.scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .left
    self.scoreLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .bottom
```

But it looks weird after using autolayout.

I'm a newcomer in SpriteKit. And I am used to work with [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint), [NSAutoresizingMaskOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsautoresizingmaskoptions?language=objc) or [NSLayoutAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor?language=objc).

Could you please recommend me some alternative for iOS instead of direct positioning to support multiple devices like iPhone 5, 6, 6Plus & iPads.

I've already read [SKNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode?language=objc) documentation. And there is nothing besides direct positioning. I've also googled and found nothing.

PS

In any case. Thanks for attention.

Comment: Constraints do not make sense in SpriteKit like it does in UIKit.  The main feature of sprite kit is you design for 1 size, and the canvas is scaled. "Constraints" would not make sense.

Comment: Normally I like using UIKit for my HUD so that it does not affect my rendering tree, but sometimes performance just isn't that great.  So to substitute, You assign a type of "padding" to determine how much is cropped from the left of the scene.  To get the pad point, just convert the views bottom left and top right coordinates to scene space.

Comment: Looks like you are not far away from the truth, but absence of ability to make interface adaptive for different screen sizes confuses me.

Comment: Why would it confuse you.  Think of it like drawing a picture on a balloon, and then stretching the balloon to the size you want.

Comment: Wow, I think this is the answer for my question, thank! Looks like nothing more is currently possible.

Comment: Yeah, it is just the tool you are using.  It really does make developing a lot easier when you only design for 1 size.  Gone are the days of pixel perfect accuracy, because your resources will never account for every possible screen.  Plus, you want to future proof your apps, which I admit constraints also do, but in a game environment, has too many moving pieces.  Imagine having to check constraints on 100 different sprites lol.

Comment: A bit confusing. But after a bit of thinking and your explanation, it makes sense. Post your answer & I'll vote for it. "Single size+scaling". sounds nice. I'll see how it works.

Comment: I just want to constraint only static labels/buttons in the corners, nothing more. I'm not going to constraint objects in gravity field or something... :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178561/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-zevsvu).